# How to make Active Directory access SQL Server and authenticate username and password?

Tags: active-directory, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a fingerprint SQL Server I want to make the AD access the SQL Server database and check if the user had entered his fingerprint today then it will activate his username and password on AD so s/he can access the internet.

Could you please tell me how can I do it ?